# Prevent dropdown menu to be shown immediately

Tags: jquery, html

On my site I have a button to accept or deny friend request. How prevent the dropdown menu to be shown immediately after I clicked on accept button.

**html**:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs friend-request tooltiped" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Friend request in pending">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger add-friend-single-btn is-pending-friend-request dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="min-width:65px;" data-profile-id="1">
                                    <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Pending  
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
     </button>

     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li class="accept-friend-request" data-friendship-id="25" data-profile-id="1"><a href="#">Accept</a></li>
       <li class="deny-friend-request" data-friendship-id="25" data-profile-id="1"><a href="#">
                                    deny</a></li>

     </ul>
</div>
```

**jquery**:

```
//Accept friend request profile
  $('body').on('click', '.accept-friend-request', function(e){

   e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    if ($(this).hasClass('is-pending-friend-request')) {

            e.stopPropagation();
    }


    var obj = $(this);
    var friendship_id = parseInt(obj.attr('data-friendship-id'));
    var from_user_id = parseInt(obj.attr('data-profile-id'));




                      obj.closest('.friend-request').find('.is-pending-friend-request').css('background', '#82b964');
                      obj.closest('.friend-request').find('.is-pending-friend-request').html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Friend <span class="caret"></span>');
                      obj.closest('.friend-request').find('.is-pending-friend-request').addClass('is-friend');
                      obj.closest('.friend-request').find('.is-pending-friend-request').removeClass('is-pending-friend-request');

                      //obj.closest('.friend-request').find('ul li').addClass('hidden');
                      obj.closest('.friend-request').find('ul .accept-friend-request').addClass('delete-friend-relation');
                      obj.closest('.friend-request').find('ul .delete-friend-relation').html('<a href="#">Delete</a>');
                      obj.closest('.friend-request').find('ul .delete-friend-relation').removeClass('accept-friend-request');
                      obj.closest('.friend-request').find('ul .deny-friend-request').remove();


  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/foc0vh0q/

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly, please don't use the same dropdown and then change it content. Instead try 2 different dropdown and show/hide the other.
Anyway to fix your existing code add this

```
obj.closest('.friend-request').removeClass('open');
```

You can also cache friendrequest for a better performance

```
var $friendRequest = obj.closest('.friend-request');
```

then

```
$friendRequest.something
$friendRequest.something
$friendRequest.something
$friendRequest.something
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `data-toggle` here to open the dropdown and just changing the content of elements when user accepts request. All you need to do is close the dropdown when user click accepts. When you dropdown opens it add class `open` to the div. All we have to do is remove that class like this `$(this).closest('div').removeClass("open");` Check the snippet

```js
//Accept friend request profile
$('body').on('click', '.accept-friend-request', function(e) {

  e.stopImmediatePropagation();

  if ($(this).hasClass('is-pending-friend-request')) {

    e.stopPropagation();
  }


  var obj = $(this);
  var friendship_id = parseInt(obj.attr('data-friendship-id'));
  var from_user_id = parseInt(obj.attr('data-profile-id'));




  obj.closest('.friend-request').find('.is-pending-friend-request').css('background', '#82b964');
  obj.closest('.friend-request').find('.is-pending-friend-request').html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Friend <span class="caret"></span>');
  obj.closest('.friend-request').find('.is-pending-friend-request').addClass('is-friend');
  obj.closest('.friend-request').find('.is-pending-friend-request').removeClass('is-pending-friend-request');
  obj.closest('.friend-request').removeClass("open");//added this line
  obj.closest('.friend-request').find('ul .accept-friend-request').addClass('delete-friend-relation');
  obj.closest('.friend-request').find('ul .delete-friend-relation').html('<a href="#">Delete</a>');
  obj.closest('.friend-request').find('ul .delete-friend-relation').removeClass('accept-friend-request');
  obj.closest('.friend-request').find('ul .deny-friend-request').remove();




});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs friend-request tooltiped" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Friend request in pending">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger add-friend-single-btn is-pending-friend-request dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="min-width:65px;" data-profile-id="1" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Pending  
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                              </button>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="accept-friend-request" data-friendship-id="25" data-profile-id="1"><a href="#">Accept</a></li>
    <li class="deny-friend-request" data-friendship-id="25" data-profile-id="1"><a href="#">
                                deny</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/sanchitpatiyal95/foc0vh0q/9/)

Comment: Thanks! It's working... but how did you fix the problem?

Comment: Just added `obj.closest('.friend-request').removeClass("open");` line in js and check description for more understanding :).

Comment: @BenfMaappy if it helped please accept and upvote the answer :)